# facenet on coral dev board

Tags: tensorflow, google-coral, tensorflow-lite

I ran facenet model on my computer and got good results. But when I ran the same model on coral dev board , the results are not as expected. 
facenet on my computer - detects accurately,
facenet on coral dev board - very bad results.
Why is it behaving so different?
Note : using coral camera on dev board and webcam on computer.

Comment: Is your facenet model compiled for the edgetpu?

Comment: No. I have cross compiled on tensorflow(using tensorflow on arm library as suggested by you earlier).

Comment: So are you just using a normal tensorflow model for you application?
Did it goes through the whole pipeline for the tpu?
https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/

If you are using a tensorflow model, I'm still surprised with the different in results though, I imagine it'd stay the same with slower performance. I know sometimes, floating point arithmetic could yeild weird rounding errors in different cpu architectures which could cause this behavior